# mapping polar angle to 0..1

Tags: math, glsl, trigonometry

Given a cartesian position, how can you map the angle from the origin into the range 0 .. 1?

I have tried:

```
sweep = atan(pos.y,pos.x) + PI) / (2.*PI);
```

(where sweep should be between 0 and 1)

This is GLSL, so the [`atan`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/atan.xml) function is happy with two parameters (y then x)  and returns -PI ... PI

This gives 1 in the top-left quadrant, a nice gradient in the top-right going round to the bottom right quadrant and then 0 in the bottom left quadrant:

[image: A badly mapped atan]

How do I get a nice single gradient sweep instead?  I want the maximum sweep somewhere, and the minimum adjacent to it anti-clockwise.

Here's my GLSL shader code:

Vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 MVP_MATRIX;
attribute vec2 VERTEX;
varying vec2 pos;
void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP_MATRIX * vec4(VERTEX,-2,1.);
    pos = gl_Position.xy;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform vec4 COLOUR;
varying vec2 pos;
void main() {
    float PI = 3.14159265358979323846264;
    float sweep = (atan(pos.y,pos.x) + PI) / (2.*PI);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(COLOUR.rgb * sweep,COLOUR.a);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what it is you want.  There's a discontinuity in all trig functions, because the functions are periodic.  Are you objecting to the saturated green next to the black?

Comment: @duffymo yes, have clarified that in the question

Comment: @will how did you make this image? I need same but from white to black :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most programming languages have a two-parameter version of `atan`, often called `atan2` This will usually give a result in the range (-PI, PI]. To convert that to the values 0-1 you can use:

```
(atan2(y,x) + PI) / (2*PI)
```

Since your language's `atan` function takes two arguments, it probably does the same thing as `atan2`.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be using [`atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), which returns an angle in (-pi, pi). Make it into:

```
atan2(pos.y,pos.x) + PI) / (2*PI)
```